# Битрикс. Как получить множественные свойства типа строка?

Tags: битрикс

Имеется свойство типа строка все нормально выводится, теперь нужно сделать из этого свойства множественное, но вот множественное отображается уже не так как нужно.

Значения свойств это ссылки на ютуб. Для проверки использую вот такую штуку

`<?print_d($arResult['PROPERTIES']["VIDEO_LINK"]['VALUE'])?>`

На что получаю ответ:

`Array ( [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gl91tlwqA9Y [1] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=splc-CcIWRk )`

Как мне получить эти ссылки без всяких лишних знаков? Если в коде дописать номер свойства ([0] или [1]) то выводится одна ссылка и ничего лишнего.

Comment: А в чём проблема? В $arResult['PROPERTIES']["VIDEO_LINK"]['VALUE'] лежит массив из двух элементов. Каждый элемент - строка. Пробежаться по массиву и вывести все ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как в итоге нужно было.

```
<?foreach (($arResult['PROPERTIES']['VK_VIDEO_LINK']['VALUE']) as $value):
```

// Тут с этими ссылками можно что угодно делать, например вытащить ID

```
        preg_match('((_)([0-9]+))', $value, $matches3); 
        if(isset($matches3[2]) && $matches3[2] != ''){
            $idvideo = $matches3[2];
        } // ID видео
```

endforeach;?>